# Lombok Builder ignores custom setter

Tags: lombok

so, I have a class with @Builder annotation and a custom setter which have to do more than setting this.authorities

```
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Collection<Authority> authorities;

public void setAuthorities(Collection<Authority> authorities...
```

but this setter is ignored while using class builder.

Another thing strange for me is that builder still has `authorities` method even if I remove my setter. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You seem to think that `@Builder` converts a class into a builder. It does not, it generates another one. Usually, the original class should have no setters as it's immutable (that's why you need the builder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@Builder` generates its own class `classNameBuilder` with methods and fields.  That's why it's not using your setter from `@Setter` annotation. Those both annotations does not depend on each other, that's why after you removed setter builder still works.

See the Lombok's doc https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html

Could you please share more of your code so it will be easier to understand what you want to achieve?